# Trying to create a separate file I can import in JavaScript with "new" involved

Tags: javascript

I have a object, cache declared as follows:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({);
```

I want to create a separate file the I can configure all the parameters that get passed into InMemoryCache({...}).  When I create a new file called cache.js that looks like this,

```
export const cache = new InMemoryCache();
```

and then from my mail file, import it as `import {cache} from './cache.js'

I get different behavior then from my original code. I'm thinking I'm not getting what new is doing here.  Suggestions?

Comment: could you elaborate the differed behaviour.

Comment: What type of javascript you are using? In a browser or node.js?

Comment: Are you using Webpack or something similar?

Comment: I'm using React/NextJS which uses webpack and node.

Answer (score 0):

`new` is used to create a new instance of an object (in this case, `InMemoryCache`).
If you want to export this single instance that you defined using

```js
const cache = new InMemoryCache({});
```

you need to make the export as

```js
export { cache };
```

which will export the previously created instance.

If you also want to be able to create a new instance from elsewhere, you can export the constructor with

```js
export { InMemoryCache };
```

(you can merge both exports together)

And then you can later import `cache` (the instance already defined), and `InMemoryCache` (the constructor) using

```js
import { cache, InMemoryCache } from '<FILENAME>';
```